# How to get local time in another time zone

Tags: javascript, timezone

Using pure javascript (no jquery nor plugins), how do I convert one local time to another timezone?

For situation:

I am doing a countdown timer and I've set the end date as a javascript variable. I want to convert that variable to a local time depending on the client location/time zone.

```
var maintenanceEndDate = new Date("11/10/2015 00:00"); //This is the initial time,  based on the administrator's location
var maintenanceEndDateOffset = ????  //The above time converted to local time
```

and THEN I would want to convert both to UTC.

Any ideas?

Comment: Careful with the input format there.  Is that November 10th, or October 11th?  It will vary depending on the locale where the code is run.  Always prefer yyyy-mm-dd format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var now = new Date();`

This will give you the client date and time.

`now.getTimezoneOffset()`

Will give you the offset between that timezone and UTC.

Comment: @Artvader - Just to be clear, this gives you the offset between the local time and UTC *for that specific date and time*.  The offset can easily change, such as for daylight saving time.  Don't confuse a "time zone" with a "time zone offset".

Answer (score 1):

You could specify your maintenance end time in UTC and let the local browser handle the time conversion for you:

```js
var maintenanceEndDate = new Date("2015-11-10T00:00:00Z");
document.write('Local time: ' + maintenanceEndDate.toString() + '<br>')
document.write('UTC time: ' + maintenanceEndDate.toISOString())
```

Comment: Agreed, except that the input should probably also be an ISO string, such as `2015-11-10T00:00:00Z`.

Comment: I have changed my answer to use an ISO date string instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to dive into the momentjs library which does exactly what you need: http://momentjs.com/ and http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: I wanted the script to be as simple as possible without relying on external libraries. But Thanks for the suggestion.